# systemd-networkd-wait-online.service fails on startup

Tags: linux, systemd

When I tried to start my computer today GNOME normally started up. But only for few seconds. Then GNOME turned off and systemd printed some messages on the screen like 'stopping user-manager-service' and finally 'starting Wait For Network service' appeared. I waited 2 minutes and service failed. I switched myself to another TTY and executed `systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` command. Here's output:

```
Failed to execute 'pager', using next fallback pager: Permission denied
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
Loaded: loaded
Active: failed
Docs: ...
Process: 1003 ...
Main PID: 1003 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

How to solve this problem?

EDIT:

Internet works.

EDIT:

```
After upgrading the system, I was able to run gnome, but I still have this error:
● systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-16 09:56:19 CEST; 1h 14min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
    Process: 529 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 529 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

maj 16 09:54:19 antoni systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
maj 16 09:56:19 antoni systemd-networkd-wait-online[529]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out
maj 16 09:56:19 antoni systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
maj 16 09:56:19 antoni systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
maj 16 09:56:19 antoni systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
```